# How to launch a ClickOnce application with an application downloaded from a browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, clickonce, file-association

#### What I want to do

When clicking the download file link on our web application, the browser will prompt the user to `save` or `open` a file. When selecting `open` the file will open in an installed application.

#### What I have so far

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which returns the file like so:

```
return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "file.rod");
```

I have created a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) installer with a file association for the application and when prompted to `save` the file the file appears with the registered file association icon and when double clicked the application launches as expected.

However, when you select `open` the application doesn't launch, which is weird because it starts correctly when the file is opened from the file system (explorer.exe). My current thinking is that the problem either lies in the way I've set up the file association or how I'm sending the data from the browser (perhaps the content-type?).

Here's the file association registration in the manifest file:

```
<fileAssociation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
    extension=".rod"
    description="Lollipops and Ice Cream"
    progid="Rod.Document"
    defaultIcon="risque.ico" />
```

What have I missed? What should I try next?

One more thing: I know it's possible to pass query parameters to a ClickOnce installer. This is something I'm also considering trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think your content type needs to be application/x-ms-application on the return File() line; otherwise, IE will not recognize that it needs to launch it as an application.   For Firefox, I haven't tried it in the most recent version, but I remember needing a ClickOnce plugin for it to work correctly.